What is the hierarchy of sins?
Imam Al-Nawawi, in his Minhaj at-Talibin, writes:

A person suffering from hunger who finds a corpse, and at the same time eatables not forbidden but belonging to another, should, according to our school, eat the corpse, rather then take the eatables that do not belong to him.

This translation is bothersome because it at first appears as though he is speaking about human corpses. Within proper context however, it is clear he is speaking about animal corpses, i.e. carrion. However, this got me thinking about such a situation: in cases of absolute necessity, is it better to eat human corpses than to steal?
We know that in cases of necessity, the haram becomes halal. However, this ruling is confusing, because it is not as though everything that is haram automatically becomes halal; some things become halal, and other things stay haram. Al-Nawawi makes it clear that eating unlawful food is a lesser sin than stealing property. This seems to prove the existence of a hierarchy of sins, in which eating unlawful food ranks as a better deed than stealing someone’s property.
Is there a full hierarchy of sins? If so, where can I find it?

This may seem like an esoterically hypothetical question, but it has many implications. Sins are all horrible, and one should avoid them in all situations. But finding a hierarchy of sins would allow one to have an exact idea of what to do when he arrives in dire circumstances. For example, suppose I am being threatened with my life and the threatener forces me either to apostate and completely abandon the prayer, or to commit suicide. In this case, I would refer to the hierarchy: is suicide a worse sin than abandoning prayer? If so, I will abandon the prayer. If not, I will commit suicide.

Without such a hierarchy, I would have no idea what to do.
